# Dynamically getting an attribute from an object to call a function based on that attribute

Tags: python, django

I'm inspecting an object and looking for a ManyToMany field that's of model "Risk", and then after that I want to call the `obj.somefieldname.add()` method. This is what I have so far

```
    for field in [f for f in obj.__class__._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(f, models.ManyToManyField)
                  and (f.related_model._meta.object_name == Risk._meta.object_name)]:
        getattr(obj, field.name).add(...)
```

Is there a better way to do the discovery than my approach?

I have two models:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
   risk = models.ManyToManyField(Risk)
   ...

class Foo(models.Model):
   risk = models.ManyToManyField(Risk)
   ...
```

I have a function that receives an arbitrary object, if the object has a manytomanyfield that's pointing at the Risk model, I want add something to this object's manytomany risk field.

Comment: There probably is, but it's hard to say what you should do without knowing why you're doing this in the first place - what problem are you trying to solve with this solution?

Comment: @Grismar I've added more details to my question.

Comment: I'm sorry for repeating the question, but it's still not quite clear what you're trying to achieve - although it does appear you're going about it in a more complicated way than would be needed. Can you give an example of the kind of function you're talking about and show what you expect and what actually happens? (also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for tips on asking a question that's likely to get good answers) Am I understanding correctly that you want to add something to an objects's Many-to-many Risk relationship from a function, if the object has it?

Comment: @Grismar perhaps this would better explain what I'm trying to accomplish, I have a Risk class that acts as a container to note something, it has the risk type and the recommended actions (Leave door open; risk is Intrusion; recommended action is to Close doors). Bar is a class that can house a risk, and so is Foo, what I have is I have an object that comes in, I don't know if this object is of type Foo or Bar, but I know if it has a risk m2m field I should append a risk to it. That's what I'm trying to do.